# насколько безопасно отдавать третьей стороне свой id_rsa?

Tags: ssh, ssh-key

- можно ли получить доступ к твоему компьютеру по `ssh`, если ты поделился с кем-то приватным ключом?
- сможет ли кто-то подключиться к удаленному серверу, где указан твой `id_rsa.pub`, если украдет твой `id_rsa`?

Comment: Приватных ключей может быть сколько угодно разных, для разных целей. И не факт, что хотя бы один из них может дать доступ к вашему компьютеру. А вообще вопрос стоит закрыть, либо приведите его к такому виду, чтобы на него можно было однозначно ответить.

Comment: если в вопросе заменить выражения «приватный ключ«, «id_rsa» и «id_rsa.pub» на слово «пароль», суть вопроса не изменится ни на йоту. зато и вопрос (надеюсь) сразу отпадёт.

Comment: Да и да . . . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При подключении к серверу OpenSSH смотрит на файл `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`*. Если там прописана публичная часть вашего ключа из `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`, то любой злоумышленник, получивший копию приватной части вашего ключа (имеется ввиду `~/.ssh/id_rsa`), сможет подключится к серверу и действовать от вашего имени. Само по себе наличие файла `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` (если ключ оттуда не прописан в списке разрешённых) не позволяет производить подключение к серверу. Жёсткой связи тут нет.

Но вообще говоря, идея поделиться с кем-то приватной частью своего ключа — плохая, и от её надо отказаться.

<sub>* Значение по умолчанию может быть изменено настройкой AuthorizedKeysFile.</sub>